# Local Notification issue

Tags: iphone, ios, localnotification

i am using following code for local notification

```
 for (int i=0;i<newBirthDates.count;i++)
{
    NSDate *date =[Formatter1 dateFromString:[newBirthDates objectAtIndex:i ]];
    NSComparisonResult result = [date compare:todaydate];
    if(result == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotif.fireDate = date;
        localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        localNotif.alertBody = @"birthdate notification";
        localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

        localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    }
}
  newBirthdate is array with dates in it
  Formatter1 =MM/dd.
```

lets say one of the date in newbrithdate is 18/3 so what i do is i change my computer
date to 17/3 and 11.59 pm then i wait for 1 minute and it turn 18/3 but i dont get any  any notification 
 time in my simulator always same to my computer time.

Comment: did you try to print out the dates first?

Comment: yes dates are in MM/dd formate in that array

Comment: If you know your timeZone then why not set your own timezone and see if it works?

Comment: Did you check wether notification is scheduling? is it entering to if(result == NSOrderedSame){} block??

Answer (score 0):

You are storing formatted date string in array(in MM/dd format) and converting it back to date for setting notification.

Lets do you a simple check!!

```
NSDateFormatter *Formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
Formatter1.dateFormat =@"MM/dd";

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];// take current date
NSString *initialDateString =[Formatter1 stringFromDate:today]; // formatted date string(in MM/dd)


NSDate *dateFromFormatter = [Formatter1 dateFromString:initialDateString]; // Date from the formatted string(In your case taking from array)
NSString *finalDateString = [Formatter1 stringFromDate:dateFromFormatter];// formatted string from new date

// lets take a look wether both are same
NSLog(@"Initial date string: %@",initialDateString);
NSLog(@"Final date string  : %@",finalDateString);
// Both date strings are same

NSLog(@"Actual date    : %@",today);
NSLog(@"Formatted date : %@",dateFromFormatter);
//But see both dates are entirely different
```

**output**

Initial date string: 03/18
 Final date string  : 03/18
 Actual date    : 2013-03-18 12:15:45 +0000
 Formatted date : 2000-03-17 18:30:00 +0000

Then how will you get notification??

Comment: so what is solution cus dates will be always deferent user is sleeping and then app is closed and then it is 12 am and then date get changed and then it dates are same so how i will get notification that time?

Comment: Store the date as it is(date object not string).while comparing take the required components(month&day)from both dates. finally set notification. remember notification is time specific so correct the date accordingly. Change the implementation. got any doubt let me know... will help you